# Conversion between coordinate systems

Tags: unity, tilemap, coordinates

I have a chunk system that I created for my tile-based game, however I am having problems translating the coordinate in tiles of the cursor to the coordinate in chunks. This is my code so far:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class MapGeneration : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DimensionScriptable dim;
    public Tilemap ctm;
    public Tilemap nctm;
    public Grid grid;
    public Transform target;
    public int renderDistance = 1;

    private Vector2Int offset;
    private Dictionary<Vector2Int, Chunk> map;

    private void Start()
    {
        nctm.SetTile(Vector3Int.zero, dim.tiles[3]);
        int seed = 1232421;

        map = new Dictionary<Vector2Int, Chunk>();

        System.Random rng = new System.Random(seed);
        offset = new Vector2Int(rng.Next(-100000, 100000), rng.Next(-100000, 100000));
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2Int centerPoint = (Vector2Int)grid.LocalToCell(target.localPosition);
        centerPoint.x /= dim.chunkSize.x;
        centerPoint.y /= dim.chunkSize.y;

        for (int y = -renderDistance; y <= renderDistance; y++)
        {
            for (int x = -renderDistance; x <= renderDistance; x++)
            {
                Vector2Int pos = new Vector2Int(centerPoint.x + x, centerPoint.y + y);
                Chunk chunk;

                if (!map.TryGetValue(pos, out chunk))
                {
                    Chunk newChunk = new Chunk(pos, dim.chunkSize, dim.tiles, ctm, nctm);
                    newChunk.GenerateTiles(dim.scale, dim.persistance, dim.lacunarity, dim.octaves, offset);
                    newChunk.RenderTiles();

                    map.Add(pos, newChunk);
                }
                else
                {
                    chunk.RenderTiles();
                }
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector2Int mouseTile = (Vector2Int)grid.WorldToCell(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
            Vector2Int mouseChunk = new Vector2Int((mouseTile.x + dim.chunkSize.y / 2) / (dim.chunkSize.x), (mouseTile.y + dim.chunkSize.y / 2) / (dim.chunkSize.y));
            Chunk chunk;
            //Debug.Log("Mouse: " + mouseTile);
            Debug.Log("Chunk: " + mouseChunk);

            if (!map.TryGetValue(mouseChunk, out chunk))
            {
                Debug.Log(mouseTile);
                Debug.LogError("TILE NOT FOUND");
            }
            else
            {
                Vector2Int conversionVec = new Vector2Int(mouseChunk.x / 2 + dim.chunkSize.x / 2, mouseChunk.y / 2 + dim.chunkSize.y / 2);
                Vector2Int convertedCoords = mouseTile + conversionVec;
                //Debug.Log(new Vector2(convertedCoords.x % dim.chunkSize.x, convertedCoords.y % dim.chunkSize.y));
                //Vector2Int tileInChunk = new Vector2Int((mouseTile.x + dim.chunkSize.x / 2) % (dim.chunkSize.x), (mouseTile.y + dim.chunkSize.y / 2) % (dim.chunkSize.y));
                //Debug.Log("Tile: " + tileInChunk);
                //Debug.Log(new Vector2Int(Mathf.Abs((mousePos.x % dim.chunkSize.x) + dim.chunkSize.x / 2), Mathf.Abs((mousePos.y % dim.chunkSize.y) + dim.chunkSize.x / 2)));
                chunk.Modify(new Vector2Int(convertedCoords.x % dim.chunkSize.x, convertedCoords.y % dim.chunkSize.y), Tiles.WATER);
                ctm.SetTile(new Vector3Int(mouseChunk.x * dim.chunkSize.x - dim.chunkSize.x / 2, 0, mouseChunk.y * dim.chunkSize.y - dim.chunkSize.y / 2), dim.tiles[3]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void GenerateMap()
    {
        map = new Dictionary<Vector2Int, Chunk>();
    }
}
```

And this is my Chunk class (the static class method Noise.GenerateNoiseMap is always returning a constant value and as such is not relevant for this problem)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class Chunk
{
    private Vector2Int position;
    public static int width;
    public static int height;

    private int[,] modifiedMap;
    private int[,] map;

    private Tilemap ctm;
    private Tilemap nctm;
    private Tile[] tiles;

    public Chunk(Vector2Int position, Vector2Int size, Tile[] tiles, Tilemap colidableTileMap, Tilemap nonCollidableTilemap)
    {
        this.position = position;
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;
        map = new int[width, height];
        modifiedMap = new int[width, height];
        ctm = colidableTileMap;
        nctm = nonCollidableTilemap;
        this.tiles = tiles;
    }

    public void GenerateTiles(float scale, float persistance, float lacunarity, int octaves, Vector2Int mapOffset)
    {
        Vector2 offset = new Vector2(position.x * width + mapOffset.x, position.y * height + mapOffset.y);
        float[,] heightMap = Noise.GenerateHeightMap(offset, scale, persistance, lacunarity, octaves);

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                float height = heightMap[x, y];
                Tiles tileId = Tiles.STONE;

                if (height < 0.25)
                {
                    tileId = Tiles.WATER;
                }
                else if (height < 0.75)
                {
                    tileId = Tiles.GRASS;
                }

                map[x, y] = (int)tileId;
            }
        }
        map[0, 0] = (int) Tiles.GRASS;
    }

    public void RenderTiles()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                if (modifiedMap[x, y] == 0)
                {
                    if (map[x, y] == (int)Tiles.GRASS)
                    {
                        nctm.SetTile(new Vector3Int(position.x * width + x - width / 2, position.y * height + y - height / 2, 0), tiles[map[x, y]]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    ctm.SetTile(new Vector3Int(position.x * width + x - width / 2, position.y * height + y - height / 2, 0), tiles[map[x, y]]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (modifiedMap[x, y] == (int)Tiles.GRASS)
                    {
                        nctm.SetTile(new Vector3Int(position.x * width + x - width / 2, position.y * height + y - height / 2, 0), tiles[modifiedMap[x, y]]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ctm.SetTile(new Vector3Int(position.x * width + x - width / 2, position.y * height + y - height / 2, 0), tiles[modifiedMap[x, y]]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Modify(Vector2Int position, Tiles tile)
    {
        modifiedMap[position.x, position.y] = (int)tile;
        RenderTiles();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, the thing was that I wanted the least positive residue, not the signed modulo, so I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain#1082938) from [ShreevatsaR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4958/shreevatsar)

> I always use my own `mod` function, defined as
>
> ```
> int mod(int x, int m) {
>     return (x%m + m)%m;
> }
> ```
>
> Of course, if you're bothered about having *two* calls to the modulus
>   operation, you could write it as
>
> ```
> int mod(int x, int m) {
>     int r = x%m;
>     return r<0 ? r+m : r;
> }
> ```
>
> or variants thereof.
>
> The reason it works is that "x%m" is always in the range [-m+1, m-1].
>   So if at all it is negative, adding m to it will put it in the
>   positive range without changing its value modulo m.

Comment: Don't forget to Accept your answer with the green checkmark if it worked for you.